# C realloc: invalid next size, aSan says heap-use-after-free

Tags: c, realloc, address-sanitizer

I'm very sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I have looked at various other answers and they do not seem to apply to my code.
I have defined a struct Coord which is simply an x and y limited to 4 bits each.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int x:4;
    unsigned int y:4;
} Coord;
```

I am using an array of Coords by doing `Coord* snakeArr = malloc(2 * sizeof(Coord));` and keeping track of the array's size with `int snakeArrSize = 2;`. I have made this function to mimic the `unshift()` javaScript function.

```
void unshiftCoord(Coord *arr, Coord value, int *arrSize) {
  // Debugging
  printf("%li\n", (*arrSize + 1) * sizeof(Coord));
  fflush(stdout);

  // Allocate an extra slot in the array
  arr = realloc(arr, (*arrSize + 1) * sizeof(Coord));

  // Shift everything over
  for (int i = *arrSize; i > 0; i--) {
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
  }

  // Set the first value in the array
  arr[0] = value;
  // Update arrSize variable
  *arrSize += 1;
}
```

This works perfectly fine but for some reason it gives the "invalid next size" error when I call the function for the 5th time. Here is the output of my program:

```
12
16
20
24
28
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

As you can see when the new size is increased to 28, realloc() fails.
One solution I came across was to use aSan. I did this with `-fsanitize=address` in my compiler flags, and I get this right when I run: `ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free`... and a really long message. If you need it, I put it in [this google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FC-rMnLwsvPz1G_TSoUxYaLr601wWPzlckb7VXtbjLQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: It's weird that you got the error `ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free`. It doesn't look like you have a use-after-free problem - it looks like you are writing one element past the end. Try valgrind instead of ASAN - it should be able to tell you that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After successful

```
  arr = realloc(arr, (*arrSize + 1) * sizeof(Coord));
  *arrSize += 1;
```

`arr` has `*arrSize` element, so `arr[*arrSize]` is out-of-range and you cannot use that to store something.

The loop

```
  for (int i = *arrSize; i > 0; i--) {
```

should be

```
  for (int i = *arrSize - 1; i > 0; i--) {
```

Also results of `realloc()` shouldbe checked to avoid dereferencing `NULL`.

And there is one more critical point: the argument `arr` is *a copy of* what is passed, so modification to that won't affect what is passed. Therefore, if `realloc()` returns new buffer, it will get lost and original invalidated `arr` will be used in later process.
To avoid this, a pointer to variable should be passed instead of `arr` and modification of the variable should be done via the pointer.

Comment: I think I get the first problem, so I moved `*arrSize += 1;` to the end of the function. For the problem about the copy, I tried changing the parameter of the function to `Coord **arr` and then dereferencing `arr` every time I use it. But now as soon as I call the function I get "segmentation fault (core dumped)". Did I try to fix it the wrong way?

Comment: Did you modify the caller to pass pointer to the pointer to `Coord`? Also note that if you wrote like `*arr[i]`, this is wrong because `[i]` has higher precedence than `*`. You should write like `(*arr)[i]`.

Comment: I did modify the caller, but you were right, the problem was `*arr[i]`. I changed them all to `(*arr)[i]` and it worked! Thanks so much!